# How can I output values from an Excel table on my website?

Tags: python, php, html

In my Excel spreadsheet there are several values, both numbers and text. I would like to display these values on a web page inform of graphs. But I have no idea how to solve this, I thought of Python and PHP.

I try to do it with HTML and it is impossible.

Comment: There are lots of answers here on SO how to read data from excel files in both php and python. There are answers how to display charts on web pages. You need to start programming the solution in your chosen language and ask specific question along the way as I do not think anybody will give you a full working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file using the pandas library and create a html code with the same library.

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.read_excel(yourfilepath)
df.to_html()
```